# Break table with many columns into multiple pages without cutting off content on the right

Tags: html, css

I have a table with cell values that can be very long; I'm trying to print this ideally without writing markup specific for print (CSS for print via media queries is fine). How can I achieve the following:

1. Repeat the first column across pages (the first column are labels)
2. Avoid cutting off column content or rescaling when printing; instead make a page break when a column is about to be cut off

What I'm seeing in Chrome/FF is that there is no page break at all; only one page prints and the rest of the content is cut off. My current markup is like this:

```css
@media print {
    table {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    table, tbody, tr {
        page-break-inside: auto;
    }
    td {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        page-break-after: auto;
        page-break-before: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>LABEL1</td>
        <td>CBA</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LABEL2</td>
        <td>JKL</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LABEL3</td>
        <td>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td>
        <td>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td>
        <td>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td>
        <td>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LABEL4</td>
        <td>ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA</td>
        <td>ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA</td>
        <td>ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA</td>
        <td>ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If your font size is larger than the available print space, it will be cutoff if you don't rescale it.

Comment: The font size ultimately doesn't matter. My example shows 4 columns but realistically I can have 2-20; this is really a rotated table